# How to upload many files via FT by using python?

Tags: python, ftp

I have many files (can be a big amount of files), which I want to upload to my FTP server.

How should I implement it?
By using only one connection until error or close/open each time.. I need also check, is the FTP-server alive or not.
I use ftplib.

```
from ftplib import FTP 

def ftp_upload(remotefile):
  with open(localfile, 'rb') as f:  
    ftp.storlines('STOR %s' % remotefile, f)  

  #ftp.close()


ftp = FTP()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)

retry = False

while True:
    try:
        if retry:
            /* find list of files * remote_path="some_file"/
            ftp_upload(remote_path)
        else:
            ftp.connect('host', port) 
            ftp.login('user','pass')
            retry=True

    except Exception as e:
        print("error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
        rint("Retrying...")
        retry = False
```

Comment: Why would you *"close/open each time"*?

Comment: I don't know the correct way. Probably there is some session time or another problem with FTP..

Comment: So tell us what your problem is, instead of asking vague question like this.

Comment: I suggested approach, posted above. But I'm not sure, this is the best way how to handle FTP-uploading of many files. So, maybe this code has some bugs/cons and I should use something different.